# Error while setting filter on queue in ArtemisMQ

Tags: broker, activemq-artemis

I have a problem trying to configure filter on queue through config for ArtemisMQ (broker.xml):

```
<address name="foo">
    <multicast>
      <queue name="filtered_foo">
        <durable>true</durable>
        <filter string="bar <> 42"/>
      </queue>
    </multicast>
</address>
```

Trying start broker I have an error:

```
[Fatal Error] :207:30: The value of attribute "string" associated with an element type "filter" must not contain the '<' character.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 207; columnNumber: 30; The value of attribute "string" associated with an element type "filter" must not contain the '<' character.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.XMLUtil.readerToElement(XMLUtil.java:90)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.XMLUtil.stringToElement(XMLUtil.java:55)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.FileDeploymentManager.readConfiguration(FileDeploymentManager.java:76)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.FileBroker.start(FileBroker.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.Run.execute(Run.java:82)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:149)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:97)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:129)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:49)
```

If I set selector on consumer with same filter string it works:

```
auto consumer = session->createConsumer("foo::filtered_foo", "bar <> 42");
```

According to Artemis documentation syntax for config must be the same as for selectors. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `filter` is being defined in XML which has its own rules for what characters are allowed and what characters are not allowed.  Simply put, your XML isn't valid.  Try using this:

```
<filter string="bar &lt;> 42"/>
```

By escaping the `<` character the XML should parse correctly.